# POSTing a login form to coursera using R;cannot see the form when GET

Tags: r, forms, post, authentication, rcurl

I am trying to post a login form to sign into coursera, but I am not yet successful.

With coursera, the login form on the login URL is brought up foreward. Before even posting the login form if I get the website via `getURL`, and then writing it to a file, I cannot see the fields related to username and password, basically I do not see the actual form, which by the way using a Firebug or inspect element I can see.

For example if you try the following code, you can see the output html that we get by reading the page.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

defaultOptions <- curlOptions(
    httpheader = list('user-agent'=str_c(R.version$platform,R.version$version.string,sep=", ")),
followlocation = TRUE,
cookiefile = "RCurlCookies.txt",
cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))

options(RCurlOptions = defaultOptions)
handle <- getCurlHandle()
url <- getURL("https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login", 
          curl = handle, .opts = defaultOptions, ssl.verifyhost = 0L, ssl.verifypeer = 0L)

con <- file("output.html")
writeLines(con = con, url)
close(con)
options(RCurlOptions = list())
```

So I am guessing that that is why the `POST` also does not work, because it does not see the form. If it did then I could use whether `RHTMLForms' or use`postForm` to actually authenticate by creating a handle and giving some parameters.

```
postForm(url, .params = params, curl = curl, style="post", cainfo=signatures)
```

I wish to be able to post a login form with some username:"username" and some password:"xxxxxxxxxx".

P.S any other method with R would also be good, so far I was able to deal with RSelenium, which has a lot of fuss about browser version, and creating a session, otherwise would have been nice.

Comment: _"You may download content from our Services only for your personal, non-commercial use, unless you obtain Coursera's written permission to otherwise use the content."_ Despite the low efficacy of asking for truthful intent in a public forum, you should prbly state what you're scraping & why in order to avoid potentially piling on others to a Coursera C&D or lawsuit. I'm having difficulty envisioning why one wld need to scrape Coursera.

Comment: I do not aim to use any scraping other than for my own personal use and that is not in anyway intended in the question. The question simply asks how a form shown by Firebug or any source inspector, is not captured when a page is downloaded via RCurl. I intend to use the form to login to my own personal profile. Thanks for pasting the terms, and as it states only for personal, non-commercial use. There are many questions about the logins in SO, and  I used those but was not successful for this website.

Comment: I'm sure others will answer, but I now don't have enough info to ensure I'm not helping someone appropriate content for monetary gain. I still can't envision why one would need to scrape authenticated content from Coursera. No need to respond. As I said, others will probably assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the docker Selenium to interact with the browser and submit forms, and that does not seem to have any problems and works fine. I highly recommend using the Selenium either in R or other languages such as python.